# why sum on lists is (sometimes) faster than itertools.chain?

Tags: python, list

I answered several questions here by using this to "flatten" a list of lists:

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> sum(l,[])
```

it works fine and yields:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

although I was told that the `sum` operator does `a = a + b` which is not as performant as `itertools.chain`

My planned question was "why is it possible on lists where it is prevented on strings", but I made a quick benchmark on my machine comparing `sum` and `itertools.chain.from_iterable` on the same data:

```
import itertools,timeit

print(timeit.timeit("sum(l,[])",setup='l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]'))
print(timeit.timeit("list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))",setup='l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]'))
```

I did that several times and I always get about the same figures as below:

```
0.7155522836070246
0.9883352857722025
```

To my surprise, `chain` - recommended over `sum` for lists by everyone in several comments on my answers - is much slower.

It's still interesting when iterating in a `for` loop because it doesn't actually create the list, but when creating the list, `sum` wins.

So should we drop `itertools.chain` and use `sum` when the expected result is a `list` ?

EDIT: thanks to some comments, I made another test by increasing the number of lists

```
s = 'l = [[4,5,6] for _ in range(20)]'
print(timeit.timeit("sum(l,[])",setup=s))
print(timeit.timeit("list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))",setup=s))
```

now I get the opposite:

```
6.479897810702537
3.793455760814343
```

Comment: Use more lists. Your tests are dominated by constant factors, not asymptotic behavior.

Comment: verify for huge lists. You will see the huge difference

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I just did, now I'm convinced. Which gives me another subject for a new question :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your test inputs are tiny. At those scales, the horrific O(n^2) asymptotic runtime of the `sum` version isn't visible. The timings are dominated by constant factors, and `sum` has a better constant factor, since it doesn't have to work through iterators.

With bigger lists, it becomes clear that `sum` is not at all designed for this kind of thing:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))',
...               'l = [[i] for i in xrange(5000)]; import itertools',
...               number=1000)
0.20425895931668947
>>> timeit.timeit('sum(l, [])', 'l = [[i] for i in xrange(5000)]', number=1000)
49.55303902059097
```

Answer (score 11):

**For the first question**, "To my surprise, chain - recommended over sum for lists by everyone in several comments on my answers - is much slower", there are two reasons for your observed timings:

- For small inputs, the timings are dominated by function call overhead. Calling both `list` and `chain.from_iterable` is more expensive than calling just `sum`.  The actual work of concatenating the small inputs is faster than the work for making the function and method calls.
- For larger inputs, the expected quadratic behavior of the `a = a + b` logic will dominate.

**For your other question**, "why is it possible on lists where it is prevented on strings", the answer is that we can't detect and report all quadratic cases, so we just report on the one a user is most likely to stumble on accidentally.

Also, the work-around of `''.join(list_of_strings)` is harder to figure-out if you don't already know about it.  In contrast, performant work-arounds for lists are much easier to find, `t=[]; for s in list_of_lists: t+=s`.

**Using the non-itertools alternative**, you should be able to get reasonable performance with simple in-place list extensions:

```
result = []
for seq in list_of_lists:
    result += seq
```

The loop runs at "python-speed" instead of "C-speed", but there is no function call overhead, there is no extra iteration layer, and more importantly, the list concatenation can take advantage of the known length of the input so it can pre-allocate the space needed for the result (this is called a *__length_hint__*).

**One other thought**, you should never trust timings that involve growing lists incrementally.  The internal logic uses *realloc()* to resize the list as it grows.  In timing suites, the environment is favorable and realloc can often extend in-place because no other data is in the way.  However, the same logic used in real code can perform much worse because the more fragmented memory causes realloc to have to copy all the data to a larger empty space.  In other words, the timings may not be at all indicative of the actual performance in real code that you care about.

**In any case**, the main reason that *sum()* is the way it is is because Guido van Rossum and Alex Martelli thought that is what is best for the language:

- https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-April/034853.html
- http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-dev/51956/