# could sum be faster on lists

Tags: python, performance, list, sum

This is somehow a follow-up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772054/why-sum-on-lists-is-sometimes-faster-than-itertools-chain)

So first, you'll notice that you cannot perform a `sum` on a list of strings to concatenate them, python tells you to use `str.join` instead, and that's good advice because no matter how you use `+` on strings, the performance is bad.

The "cannot use `sum`" restriction doesn't apply to `list`, and though, `itertools.chain.from_iterable` is the preferred way to perform such list flattening.

But `sum(x,[])` when `x` is a list of lists is definitively bad.

But should it stay that way?

I compared 3 approaches

```
import time
import itertools

a = [list(range(1,1000)) for _ in range(1000)]

start=time.time()
sum(a,[])
print(time.time()-start)

start=time.time()
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))
print(time.time()-start)


start=time.time()
z=[]
for s in a:
    z += s
print(time.time()-start)
```

results:

- `sum()` on the list of lists: 10.46647310256958. Okay, we knew.
- `itertools.chain`: 0.07705187797546387
- custom accumulated sum using in-place addition: 0.057044029235839844 (can be faster than `itertools.chain` as you see)

So `sum` is way behind because it performs `result = result + b` instead of `result += b`

So now my question:

Why can't `sum` use this accumulative approach when available?

(That would be transparent for already existing applications and would make possible the use of the `sum` built-in to flatten lists efficiently)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could try to make *sum()* smarter, but Alex Martelli and Guido van Rossum wanted to keep it focused on arithmetic summations.

FWIW, you should get reasonable performance with this simple code:

```
result = []
for seq in mylists:
    result += seq
```

For your other question, "why can't sum use this accumulative approach when available?", see this comment for builtin_sum() in Python/bltinmodule.c:

```
    /* It's tempting to use PyNumber_InPlaceAdd instead of
       PyNumber_Add here, to avoid quadratic running time
       when doing 'sum(list_of_lists, [])'.  However, this
       would produce a change in behaviour: a snippet like

         empty = []
         sum([[x] for x in range(10)], empty)

       would change the value of empty. */
```

Comment: Maybe it could be tweaked to check if `empty` is empty, and use another empty list in that case (or make a copy if not too big). That would be transparent and would not cost a lot of CPU (copied the comment made to the other answerer)

Comment: Language design is very nuanced.  Tricky tweaks can lead to other unexpected behaviors.  And if people got in the habit of using *sum()*  for non-numeric work, they are more likely to fall prey to quadratic behavior with other types, ``sum(list_of_tuples, ())`` or ``sum(list_of_sets, set())``.  And even if those were made performant, there is still some question of whether the word *sum* is the clearest way to express the business logic concepts of *concatenate* or *set.union* or "flatten".   Guido's design instincts have an excellent track record. It is perilous to second-guess the BDFL ;-)

Comment: that's a good point. In that case, why can't we just prevent the usage of `sum` in those cases like it was smartfuly done with strings ? maybe in python 4?

Comment: It's always great to see an answer from a Python core dev on questions about Python internals and design decisions.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* It's tempting to use PyNumber_InPlaceAdd instead of
           PyNumber_Add here, to avoid quadratic running time
           when doing 'sum(list_of_lists, [])'.  However, this
           would produce a change in behaviour: a snippet like
             empty = []
             sum([[x] for x in range(10)], empty)
           would change the value of empty. */
temp = PyNumber_Add(result, item);
```

Taken from Python's built-in source code https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2146
Line:2342

Comment: nice find! makes sense. and for once I don't mind a "code only answer"

Comment: Maybe it could be tweaked to check if `empty` is empty, and use another empty list in that case (or make a copy if not too big). That would be transparent and would not cost a lot of CPU... If Guido reads that ... :)

Comment: Yep making a copy for internal use would do the trick.. Plus there wouldn't be any compatibility issues as well..

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, we can trick the interpreter into letting us use `sum` on strings by passing an appropriate custom class instance as the `start` arg to `sum`.

```
class Q(object):
    def __init__(self, data=''):
        self.data = str(data)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.data

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Q(self.data + str(other))

print(sum(['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], Q()))
```

**output**

```
abcdefghi
```

Of course, this *is* a rather silly thing to do. :)

Comment: silly BUT the same thing could be done with lists with in-place add coded in `__add__`, so it's a good idea.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I guess so, but it's hard to argue with the points Raymond makes. OTOH, rather than tweaking `sum` to handle this operation efficiently, `list` could get a new method, eg `.merge` (giving it a `.join` method would lead to a world of confusion).

Comment: Good idea, and block `sum` (but that would break some programs, like the `xrange`=>`range` did.