# How can I replace a text delimited string list item with multiple list items in a python list?

Tags: python

Given a list:

```
mylist = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse_bear', 'lion_tiger_rabbit', 'ant']
```

I'd like a one-liner to return a new list:

```
['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bear', 'lion', 'tiger', 'rabbit', 'ant']
```

Comment: is this a code golf? one-liner seems an unneccessary restriction.

Comment: This question really confuses me - I get that trying to write 1-liners is a fun exercise, but I assumed that that sort of thing was 'frowned upon' - this is a low effort question with dubious requirements and I was surprised that everyone was so enthusiastic about it.

Comment: well the goal was to get a pythonic one liner, not a perl-y, one liner... so readable and semantically clever while also logical and efficient... :P

Comment: I thought for sure a list comprehension answer would take this for elegance but in the end the simple join and split was fastest and easiest to read - surprised to say the least!

Comment: Although I love list comps, one-liners are over-rated. I'd do this with traditional loops.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another trick is first to join the list with underscores and then re-split it:

```
"_".join(mylist).split('_')
```

Comment: clever sidestep! and the fastest solution... this works for my use case too

Answer (score 6):

Just use 2 `for` clauses in your comprehension, e.g.:

```
>>> mylist = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse_bear', 'lion_tiger_rabbit', 'ant']
>>> [animal for word in mylist for animal in word.split('_')]
['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bear', 'lion', 'tiger', 'rabbit', 'ant']
```

Comment: very similar to my response and thaavik's but sooo much more readable and pythonic - thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is not a one liner, but is nevertheless a valid option to consider if you want to return a generator:

```
def yield_underscore_split(lst):
     for x in lst:
         yield from x.split('_')
```

```
>>> list(yield_underscore_split(mylist))
['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bear', 'lion', 'tiger', 'rabbit', 'ant']
```

---

Original answer valid only for versions Python 3.3-3.7, kept here for interested readers. Do not use!

```
>>> list([(yield from x.split('_')) for x in l]) 
['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bear', 'lion', 'tiger', 'rabbit', 'ant']
```

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Ty. If OP is on 3.3 or above I would recommend this as being succinct as hell :)

Comment: This is actually invalid syntax in Python 3.8 and up (a deprecation warning is issued in 3.7), don't use `yield` in comprehensions! See [yield in list comprehensions and generator expressions](//stackoverflow.com/q/32139885)

Answer (score 3):

using the [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) to flatten a list you could do this:

```
from itertools import chain

mylist = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse_bear', 'lion_tiger_rabbit', 'ant']

new_list = list(chain.from_iterable(item.split('_') for item in mylist))
print(new_list) 
# ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bear', 'lion', 'tiger', 'rabbit', 'ant']
```

...or does the import statement violate your one-liner requirement?

Answer (score 3):

Since so many answers here were posted (over ten), I thought it'd be beneficial to show some timing stats to compare the different methods posted:

```
-----------------------------------------
AChampion time: 2.6322
-----------------------------------------
hiro_protagonist time: 3.1724
-----------------------------------------
Eugene_Sh time: 1.0108
-----------------------------------------
cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ time: 3.5386
-----------------------------------------
jdehesa time: 2.9406
-----------------------------------------
mogga time: 3.1645
-----------------------------------------
Ajax1234 time: 2.4659
-----------------------------------------
```

Here's the script I used to test:

```
from timeit import timeit

setup = """
from itertools import chain
mylist = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse_bear', 'lion_tiger_rabbit', 'ant']
"""

methods = {
    'AChampion': """[animal for word in mylist for animal in word.split('_')]""",
    'hiro_protagonist': """list(chain.from_iterable(item.split('_') for item in mylist))""",
    'Eugene_Sh': """'_'.join(mylist).split('_')""",
    'cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ': """list([(yield from x.split('_')) for x in mylist])""",
    'jdehesa': """sum((s.split("_") for s in mylist), [])""",
    'mogga': """[i for sublist in [j.split('_') for j in mylist] for i in sublist]""",
    'Ajax1234': """list(chain(*[[i] if "_" not in i else i.split("_") for i in mylist]))"""
}

print('-----------------------------------------')
for author, method in methods.items():
    print('{} time: {}'.format(author, round(timeit(setup=setup, stmt=method), 4)))
    print('-----------------------------------------')
```

Each method is tested against the sample list given in the question about one million times. To keep things readable, each timing result was rounded to four decimal places.

---

**Note:** If you have a new, **unique** method that has not been posted here yet, contact me in the comments and I'll try to add a timing for it too.

Answer (score 1):

Split each item into sublists and flatten them:

`[item for sublist in mylist for item in sublist.split("_")]`

Comment: ha... very similar to mine below although I think I prefer the @jdehesa answer for it's readability

Comment: yours might be more performant and also maybe a little more readable than mine

Answer (score 1):

One-liners are over-rated. Here's a solution using a "traditional" `for` loop.

```
mylist = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse_bear', 'lion_tiger_rabbit', 'ant']

out = []
for s in mylist:
    if '_' in s:
        out.extend(s.split('_'))
    else:
        out.append(s)

print(out)
```

**output**

```
['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bear', 'lion', 'tiger', 'rabbit', 'ant']
```

This also works:

```
out = []
for s in mylist:
    out.extend(s.split('_'))
```

It's shorter, but I think the previous version is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
mylist = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse_bear', 'lion_tiger_rabbit', 'ant']
result = sum((s.split("_") for s in mylist), [])
print(result)
>>> ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bear', 'lion', 'tiger', 'rabbit', 'ant']
```

Comment: don't use `sum` for lists. performance suffers a lot (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593904/could-sum-be-faster-on-lists)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I wasn't aware of that (or I was and then I forgot). I may still prefer `sum` to a nested generator in small cases for clarity (for lack of a `flatten` or `concatenate` function in the standard library), but it's good to know the performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
[i for sublist in [j.split('_') for j in mylist] for i in sublist]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse_bear', 'lion_tiger_rabbit', 'ant']
animals = [a for item in mylist for a in item.split('_')]
print (animals)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
from itertools import chain

mylist = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse_bear', 'lion_tiger_rabbit', 'ant']

new_list = list(chain(*[[i] if "_" not in i else i.split("_") for i in mylist]))
```

Output:

```
['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bear', 'lion', 'tiger', 'rabbit', 'ant']
```

Answer (score -1):

what I would actually do:

```
newlist = []

for i in mylist:
    newlist += i.split('_')
```

Comment: this isn't a one-liner.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm aware it isn't a one-liner, but it's code I would actually use seeing as a nested list comprehension is the other option.