# Why does python forbid the use of sum with strings?

Tags: python, string, sum

Technically, in Python, one would expect that that anything which has the `__add__` method implemented should be able to use the `sum` function.

Strings have `__add__` implemented as concatenation:

```
"abc "+"def"
> 'abc def'
```

`sum` takes a start value as second argument which by default is the *int* `0` as can be seen by:

```
sum([])
```

> 0

```
sum([], 7)
```

> 7

That is why doing `sum(["abc", "def"])` doesn't work, because it tries to add `0` to "abc":

```
sum(["abc", "def"])
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

But giving a string as the start value of `sum`, it should work. But it doesn't work, because in the implementation of `sum`, there is an ad hoc check to see if the start value is a string (or other unwanted types) and it raises a type error if the start value is a string:

```
sum(["sf", "34", "342"], "")
```

> TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]

Why does Python go through the trouble of implementing hand-crafted exceptions on certain types in `sum`? The simpler, more pythonic way would be for sum to work with anything that has an implementation of `__add__`, no?

One can see that without this check `sum` would work with strings by defining a "zero" class which when added to anything returns the other thing. If we use that as the starting element, then it bypasses the check (because it is not a string) and sum can be used to add strings:

```
sum(["a", "b", "c"], type("_", (), {"__add__": lambda _, o: o})())
```

> 'abc'

Comment: If there is to be only one obvious way to do this, then I'm happy with `''.join(["sf", "34", "342"])`, since string concatenation is better described as _joining_ than _summing_.

Comment: *"There should be one and preferably only one obvious way to do it."* - If `sum` was interchangeable with `str.join` there'd be *two* ways to do it…

Comment: one can argue about why is this allowed for `list`, though, as this is clearly the same counter-performance issue.

Comment: @deceze where does your quote come from?

Comment: the main issue is the quadratic effect. `sum` has to do `result = result + x` for each `x`, which takes longer and longer when `result` increases (same issue with lists...). `sum` cannot use the starting argument to accumulate, even for lists

Comment: [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thank you for this information. And yes your point about the lists is a good one.

Comment: related (but about lists): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593904/could-sum-be-faster-on-lists?s=1|54.8272 I've been there :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I whish lists offered the syntax `[].join([lst1, lst2, ...])` instead of `list(itertools.chain(lst1, lst2, ...))` (and why not even tuples), I end up summing them for simplicity in many cases...

Comment: @jdehesa that's very true. a pity to have to use `itertools` to get an acceptable speed. There's also the double flat listcomp for this: `[z for y in x for z in y]`