# Empty tuple as 2nd parameter to sum()

Tags: python

Why does the 2nd parameter to the sum() can be an empty tuple? Shouldn't it be a number according to https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum?

```
>>> tmp=((1,2), ('a','b'))
>>> sum(tmp, ())
(1, 2, 'a', 'b')
```

Comment: note that you should not use that to flatten tuples because the complexity is just awful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2nd parameter is the start value. This is not an index to start at, but a value to start the sum.

For example:

`sum([1,2,3], 0)` is the same as `0 + 1 + 2 + 3`

`sum([1,2,3], 6)` is the same as `6 + 1 + 2 + 3`

`sum(((1,2), ('a','b')), ())` is the same as `() + (1,2) + ('a','b')`

Since start is 0 by default if you didn't specify a value for it you would get

`0 + (1,2) + ('a','b')`

Which gives

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'`

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: because `+` (used by `sum`) can be redefined, you need someway of providing a type-appropriate starting value if you don't provide an iterable of numeric values.

---

The second argument is used as the "starting point" in the sum. It's basically a starting point for the sum:

```
>>> sum([1,2,3])
6
>>> sum([1,2,3], 0)
6
>>> sum([1,2,3], 2)
8
```

Its default value is 0, which causes problems if the sequence you want to sum isn't numeric, as `0 + (1, 2)` isn't defined. Instead, you need to provide a value that *can* be added to elements of your sequence; while 0 is the identity for numeric addition, `sum` doesn't know what an equivalent value for tuple concatenation is, and you must provide it directly.

```
>>> sum(((1,2), ('a', 'b')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
>>> sum(((1,2), ('a', 'b')), ())
(1, 2, 'a', 'b')
>>> sum(((1,2), ('a', 'b')), (True,))
(True, 1, 2, 'a', 'b')
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57043468/6451573) explains the default parameter, but `sum` should *never* be used to flatten tuples or lists because of the quadratic aspect. See [could sum be faster on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593904/could-sum-be-faster-on-lists)

So:

> Why does the 2nd parameter to the sum() can be an empty tuple? Shouldn't it be a number

Yes, it *should* be a number and `sum` should always apply to number elements if you want to keep that efficient. This default parameter is here to provide an alternative to `0` or `0.0`.

Each time it encounters an item to sum, it doesn't perform in-place addition but something like (internally):

```
result = result + new_item
```

Which results in a `O(n**2)` complexity on `list` or `tuple` because old contents needs to be copied at each iteration. So don't do this (note that it's explicitly blocked for `str` type).

Instead, use a double flat comprenhension and create a `tuple` out of it:

```
tmp=((1,2), ('a','b'))

result = tuple(x for st in tmp for x in st)
```

If your tuple of tuples has a lot of elements, you'll see the speed difference.