# How to repeat a word based on its frequency of occurrence in a row with multiple words in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am working on a data set . It's first row looks like this:

Column1        Column2

1       [food=3, party=2,....]
  2       [ocean=2, fish=3, surf=2,....] 
  .       ..................
  .       ..................
  .       .................. (Column1 has serial numbers and Column2 has the list of words with frequencies.)

Each row has multiple words with their respective frequencies.

I would like to convert the column2  as follows:

[food, food, food, party, party.....] and so on.

I am finding it difficult and don't know where to start. I tried tokenizing, but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What's the format of your data? Is that a list of strings? A data frame? A dictionary?

Comment: It is a pandas dataframe

Comment: Then please represent your data accordingly. It's not clear if "food" and "party" are column names or values of a field.

Comment: Hi, changed it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are starting with a list of lists of strings, you could do this:

```
dataset = [
    ['food=3', 'party=2'],
    ['word=2', 'apple=3'],
]

def multiply_word(item):
    word, freq = item.split('=')
    return [word] * int(freq)

result = [
    sum((multiply_word(item) for item in row), [])
    for row in dataset
]

result
# [
#     ['food', 'food', 'food', 'party', 'party'], 
#     ['word', 'word', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple']
# ]
```

Or you could use this "one-liner" (inspired by @jp_data_analysis's answer):

```
[
    sum(
        ([word] * int(freq) for word, freq in (item.split('=') for item in row)),
        []
    )
    for row in dataset
]
```

If you have a lot of words in each row, then you should probably use `itertools.chain` instead of `sum`. See  [why sum on lists is (sometimes) faster than itertools.chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772054/why-sum-on-lists-is-sometimes-faster-than-itertools-chain) .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data in a list

```
l=['food=3', 'party=2']

s=pd.Series(l).str.split('=',expand=True)# split by sep `=`

s.iloc[:,0].repeat(s.iloc[:,1].astype(int)).tolist()# using repeat 
Out[549]: ['food', 'food', 'food', 'party', 'party']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

```
from itertools import chain

data = [['food=3', 'party=2'],
        ['drink=5', 'sleep=1']]

def repeater(lst):
    return list(chain(*([j[0]]*int(j[1]) for j in (i.split('=') for i in lst))))

list(map(repeater, data))

# [['food', 'food', 'food', 'party', 'party'],
#  ['drink', 'drink', 'drink', 'drink', 'drink', 'sleep']]
```