# How to get a set from a Pandas series formed by lists of terms

Tags: python, pandas, set

I have a Pandas Series formed by list of terms:

```
my_series = pd.Series([['a','b','c'], ['a','d'], [], ['e']])
```

Is there a better/more elegant/faster way of get a set of unique terms than doing like this?:

```
lt = set()
for l in my_series.tolist():
    lt = lt.union(l)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O(n) extended iterable unpacking with `set.union`.

```
>>> set().union(*my_series)
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
```

If you prefer old-fashioned, there's the set-comprehension equivalent -

```
>>> {y for x in my_series for y in x}
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
```

Comment: My speed tests seem to show that your first solution is the fastest for large lists, but they are all (including OP's solution) very close.

Answer (score 3):

`sum` with `[]`, then using `set`

```
set(sum(my_series,[]))#set(my_series.sum())

Out[85]: {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
```

Or using reduce

```
set(functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, my_series.tolist()))
Out[90]: {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
```

With `pandas` `unique`

```
pd.DataFrame(my_series.tolist()).stack().unique()
Out[93]: array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], dtype=object)
```

With `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
np.unique(np.concatenate(my_series))
Out[95]: array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], dtype='<U32')
```

Or with loop

```
set(x for y in my_series for x in y)
```

Comment: using `sum` or `reduce` to flatten the lists can be slow: [why sum on lists is (sometimes) faster than itertools.chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772054/why-sum-on-lists-is-sometimes-faster-than-itertools-chain)

Comment: Not sure if this is better, but another way: `functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x|y, map(set, my_series))`

Comment: @pault sum and reduce all slow for sure. Performance side , op's solution can beat most of  my answers

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `itertools.chain` with `set`:

```
from itertools import chain

s = pd.Series([['a','b','c'], ['a','d'], [], ['e']])

res = set(chain.from_iterable(s))

print(res)

# {'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
```

---

**Performance benchmarking**

Note: performance will be system and data dependent. Do test on your own data.

```
from itertools import chain

lst = [['a','b','c'], ['a','d'], [], ['e']]

s = pd.Series(lst*1000000)

def cs(my_series):
    return set().union(*my_series)

def cs2(my_series):
    return {y for x in my_series for y in x}

def jp(my_series):
    return set(chain.from_iterable(my_series))

def pt(my_series):
    return {x for x in chain.from_iterable(my_series)}

%timeit cs(s)   # 333 ms per loop
%timeit cs2(s)  # 433 ms per loop
%timeit jp(s)   # 294 ms per loop
%timeit pt(s)   # 402 ms per loop
```

Comment: my benchmarking has your solution as virtually tied with cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's. But like I said, they're all very close so it's hard to make a definitive call. (I ran the test multiple times and the ordering was consistent)

Comment: Yeh I believe you. Performance will be system specific, OP should test with their data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use set comprehension with `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
from itertools import chain

my_series = pd.Series([['a','b','c'], ['a','d'], [], ['e']])
print({x for x in chain.from_iterable(my_series)})
#{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
```

---

**Timing Results** (python 2.7)

```
import string
import numpy as np
N = 1000
a = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
my_series = pd.Series(
    [
        np.random.choice(a, size=np.random.randint(1,10), replace=False) 
        for _ in range(N)
    ]
)

%%timeit
lt = set()
for l in my_series.tolist():
    lt = lt.union(l)
#1000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 ms per loop (OP)

%%timeit
lt = {x for x in chain.from_iterable(my_series)}
#1000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 ms per loop (pault)

%%timeit
lt = set().union(*my_series)
#1000 loops, best of 3: 1.16 ms per loop (cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ)

%%timeit
lt = set(chain.from_iterable(my_series))
#1000 loops, best of 3: 1.17 ms per loop (jpp)
```