# Concatenating all arrays in a bigger array python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a big array with many subarrays inside and am trying to join all of the ones inside. I know how to concatenate arrays, but since the number of inner arrays varies, I don't know to make one function to concatenate these ones. I understand that i'll need one or possibly more loops, but am not sure how to do it. So far I have been doing it manually like this and keep going till i get to the last index:

```
ldata  = ldata[0]+ldata[1]+ldata[2]+ldata[3]+ldata[4]
```

where ldata is the bigger list, and all of the indexes are the inner lists. How do I do this?

Edit: Here is an example

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Comment: Could you add an example?

Comment: Look at `reduce()` or `functools.reduce()` (depending on Python version)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I would accept more if I could but Hochl's one was the simplest and I saw it first.

Comment: @AthreyaDaniel: The superficial simplicity of `sum` hides a quadratic amount of copying happening under the hood. You say you have "a big array with many subarrays inside"; with a large amount of subarrays, you could literally spend hours to weeks waiting for `sum` when a more efficient implementation would finish in under a second.

Comment: I suggest you accept the other answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

a = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
result = list(chain.from_iterable(a))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grab each sublist and add to a new list.

```
new_ldata = []
for sublist in ldata:
    new_ldata += sublist
```

Comment: this solution seems to have the best performance, but don't name a variable `list` since that shadows `<class 'list'>`.

Comment: yeah, my bad.

I was going to write 'sublist', but didn't...

Answer (score 0):

If your lists are not too long, keep it simple:

```
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> sum(a, [])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I made some timing measurements:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('sum([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], [])')
6.547808872535825
>>> timeit.timeit('reduce(lambda a, c: a + c, [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], [])', setup="from functools import reduce")
10.435796303674579
```

The more lists and the longer those lists, the solution with `chain` will perform much better:

```
a = [list(range(20)) for x in range(30)]
def test_sum():    
    return sum(a, [])
def test_chain():
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))
def test_add():     
    result = []
    for i in a:
        result += i
    return result
def test_list_comprehension():
    return [x for l in a for x in l]
print(timeit.timeit(test_sum), timeit.timeit(test_chain), timeit.timeit(test_add), timeit.timeit(test_list_comprehension))
```

yields

```
18.778313734044787 7.5882537689758465 2.5082976589910686 13.912770285038278
```

That shows that adding up the arrays with a short function is pretty good too.

Comment: Nice! Although the documentation states "To concatenate a series of iterables, consider using itertools.chain()" (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Comment: Thank you, this was a simple and effective fix!

Comment: "why use a module if the builtin works equally well" - because it doesn't. Try to join a million lists with `itertools.chain`, and it won't even take a second. Try to do that with `sum`, and you'll have to come back in a few hours.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772054/why-sum-on-lists-is-sometimes-faster-than-itertools-chain

Comment: actually it kicks in much sooner, I didn't anticipate that sum was so bad ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy concatenate for this

```
import numpy as np
x = [[1,1],[2,2,2],[3],[4,4,4,4]]
concated_x = np.concatenate(x) # now in numpy array form
concated_x = list(concated_x) # if you want it back to a list form
```