# How do you combine lists of multiple dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'd like to merge a list of dictionaries with lists as values. Given

```
arr[0] = {'number':[1,2,3,4], 'alphabet':['a','b','c']}
arr[1] = {'number':[3,4], 'alphabet':['d','e']}
arr[2] = {'number':[6,7], 'alphabet':['e','f']}
```

the result I want would be

```
merge_arr = {'number':[1,2,3,4,3,4,6,7,], 'alphabet':['a','b','c','d','e','e','f']}
```

could you recommend any compact code?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: I tried to do append, Counter, and made loop using keys and values, but it is not good to apply to multiple array of dictionary.

Comment: If you're simplifying the problem and asking it here, please show how bad the data actually is..if it's just this, try using `extend`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = [{'number':[1,2,3,4], 'alphabet':['a','b','c']},{'number':[3,4], 'alphabet':['d','e']},{'number':[6,7], 'alphabet':['e','f']}]

dict = {}
for k in arr[0].keys():
    dict[k] = sum([dict[k] for dict in arr], [])
print (dict)
```

output:

```
{'number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 6, 7], 'alphabet': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f']}
```

Comment: I looking for compact code or library/function. but I think it was best in python.

Comment: oo = {}
for k in arr[0].keys():
    oo[k] = []
    for m in arr:
        oo[k] += [m[k]]

and this is my solution and reference your code. thank you!

Comment: Using `sum` to concatenate lists is very inefficient. It's fine for small lists but this results in quadratic complexity for something that can be done in linear time.[why sum on lists is (sometimes) faster than itertools.chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772054/why-sum-on-lists-is-sometimes-faster-than-itertools-chain)

Answer (score 2):

If you know these are the only keys in the `dict`, you can hard code it. If it isn't so simple, show a complicated example.

```py
from pprint import pprint


arr = [
    {
        'number':[1,2,3,4], 
        'alphabet':['a','b','c']
    },
    {
        'number':[3,4], 
        'alphabet':['d','e']
    },
    {
        'number':[6,7], 
        'alphabet':['e','f']
    }
]

merged_arr = {
    'number': [],
    'alphabet': []
}

for d in arr:
    merged_arr['number'].extend(d['number'])
    merged_arr['alphabet'].extend(d['alphabet'])

pprint(merged_arr)
```

Output:

```
{'alphabet': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f'],
 'number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 6, 7]}
```

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: As noted by @pault, the solution below is of **quadratic complexity**, and therefore not recommended for large lists. There are more optimal ways to go around it.*

*However if you’re looking for compactness and relative simplicity, keep reading.*

---

If you want a more functional form, this two-liner will do:

```
arr = [{'number':[1,2,3,4], 'alphabet':['a','b','c']},{'number':[3,4], 'alphabet':['d','e']},{'number':[6,7], 'alphabet':['e','f']}]

keys = ['number', 'alphabet']
merge_arr = {key: reduce(list.__add__, [dict[key] for dict in arr]) for key in keys}

print arr
```

Outputs:

```
{'alphabet': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f'], 'number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 6, 7]}
```

---

This **won't** merge recursively.

If you want it to work with arbitrary keys, not present in each dict, use:

```
keys = {k for k in dict.keys() for dict in arr}
merge_arr = {key: reduce(list.__add__, [dict.get(key, []) for dict in arr]) for key in keys}
```

Comment: Same [comment as on the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340332/how-do-you-combine-lists-of-multiple-dictionaries-in-python/57340477#comment101315869_57340477) - this is a really inefficient to concatenate lists. [why sum on lists is (sometimes) faster than itertools.chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772054/why-sum-on-lists-is-sometimes-faster-than-itertools-chain)

Comment: It fits OA's use case, and to be fair, they asked for « a compact code ». But you’re right, my solution is suboptimal and I can’t recommend it. You should post your solution as an answer. As for me, maybe I should delete mine?

Comment: I mean it works and the performance hit only really matters when the lists get big. Also, it's a lot easier to understand than `dict((k, list(chain.from_iterable(map(itemgetter(1), v)))) for k, v in groupby(chain.from_iterable(zip(*(sorted(d.items()) for d in arr))), itemgetter(0)))` (which I haven't really thought through to see if it's more efficient).

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that uses `defaultdict` to more easily collect the items. You could leave the result as a `defaultdict` but this version converts that to a regular dictionary. This code will work with any keys, and the keys in the various dictionaries can differ, as long as the values are lists. Therefore this answer is more general than the other answers given so far.

```
from collections import defaultdict

arr = [{'number':[1,2,3,4], 'alphabet':['a','b','c']},
       {'number':[3,4], 'alphabet':['d','e']},
       {'number':[6,7], 'alphabet':['e','f']},
]

merge_arr_default = defaultdict(list)
for adict in arr:
    for key, value in adict.items():
        merge_arr_default[key].extend(value)
merge_arr = dict(merge_arr_default)

print(merge_arr)
```

The printed result is

```
{'number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 6, 7], 'alphabet': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f']}
```