# Pyspark dataframe get all values of a column

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I want to get all values of a column in pyspark dataframe. I did some search, but I never find a efficient and short solution.

Assuming I want to get a values in the column called "name". I have a solution:

```
sum(dataframe.select("name").toPandas().values.tolist(),[])
```

It works, but it is not efficient since it converts to pandas then flatten the list... Is there a better and short solution?

Comment: There's no fast and efficient way to do it, but you *can* do way better than [using `sum` to flatten a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41772165/5858851). The best you're going to get is probably: `[x["name"] for x in dataframe.select("name").collect()]`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Below Options will give better performance than `sum`.

**Using `collect_list`**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
my_list = df.select(f.collect_list('name')).first()[0]
```

**Using RDD:**

```
my_list = df.select("name").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
```

I am not certain but in my couple of stress test, `collect_list` gives better performance. Will be great if someone can confirm.

Comment: Thanks. what is the f.collect_list('name')?  I got error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'collect_list'

Comment: @chen you need to import pyspark functions with `import pyspark.sql.functions as f`

Answer (score 0):

To get all values of a column in a list we can use **collect()** -

column_value_list = [row['<column_name>'] for row in df.select('<column_name>').collect()]