# How to append custom multiples of elements to a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

```
L = [[a1,a2,a3...100] , [b1,b2,b3...100]]
```

I want to append

```
[[c1,c1,c1..10, c2,c2,c2...10, ..., c10,c10,c10...10].
```

Is there a way where I can append it using a single line?

```
L.append([[c1]*10,[c2]*10]...)
```

The above line causes the appending as sublists. I don't want that.

Is there any way to create a custom list and append it on the fly

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show what you *do* want as a result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score -2):

Change it to

```
L.append(sum([[c1] * 10, [c2] * 10], []))
```

The `sum` function will concatenate the lists using the `+` operator

Comment: You should [not use `sum` to flatten lists of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42594311/5858851).

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: of course it does. try `sum([[1,2], [3,4]], [])`

Comment: Nvm, using a default object of list allows it to work. But timing wise it is extremely inefficient.