# Trying to combine a list of lists in python

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of lists containing tuples of x and y coordinates such as 
`[ [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)], [(7,8), (0,5)] ]` and I want to combine them in such a way where the output contains all the x coordinates together and all the y coordinates together. Essentially I'm trying to make the output be `[(1,3,5,7,0), (2,4,6,8,5)]` so that it is a 2xN matrix. I tried to do `list(zip(*b)` where `b = [[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)], [(7,8), (0,5)]]` (the original list), but that has not given me the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to flatten the nested list. You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

list(zip(*chain.from_iterable(b)))
# [(1, 3, 5, 7, 0), (2, 4, 6, 8, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, you just have to flatten your input list first.

```
>>> lst = [[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)], [(7,8), (0,5)]]
>>> lst_flat = [x for sublist in lst for x in sublist]
>>> list(zip(*lst_flat))
[(1, 3, 5, 7, 0), (2, 4, 6, 8, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a flat list first and then create a list of two tuples

```
a = [[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)], [(7,8), (0,5)]]

flat_list = [item for sublist in a for item in sublist]
b = list(zip(*flat_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest possible solution, though perhaps not as intuitive.

```
list(zip(*sum(b,[])))
```

Comment: Neither performant, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41772165/9698684